# Using Moq with Linq Any()

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a setup similar to below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void NoIntegers()
    {
        Mock<IBar> mockBar = new Mock<IBar>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        Mock<IEnumerable<int>> mockIntegers = new Mock<IEnumerable<int>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        mockBar
            .SetupGet(x => x.Integers)
            .Returns(mockIntegers.Object);

        mockIntegers
            .Setup(x => x.Any())
            .Returns(false);

        Assert.IsFalse(new Foo(mockBar.Object).AreThereIntegers());
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
        IEnumerable<int> Integers { get; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private IBar _bar;

        public Foo(IBar bar)
        {
            _bar = bar;
        }

        public bool AreThereIntegers()
        {
            return _bar.Integers.Any();
        }
    }
}
```

When it runs it fails to initialise the mock

```
Test method NoIntegers threw exception: System.NotSupportedException: Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.Any<Int32>()
```

I have tries adding `It.IsAny()` in a few forms:

```
mockIntegers
    .Setup(x => x.Any(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<int>>(), It.IsAny<Func<int, bool>>()))
    .Returns(false);

// No method with this signiture


mockIntegers
    .Setup(x => x.Any(It.IsAny<Func<int, bool>>()))
    .Returns(false);

// Throws: Test method NoIntegers threw exception: 
// System.NotSupportedException: 
// Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object:
//  x => x.Any<Int32>(It.IsAny<Func`2>())
```

What do I need to mock in order for this to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock `Integers` property only. There is no need to mock `Any()` (you can't do it anyway because it's an extension method) because it is a part of [SUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test). Here's how you should do it for two cases:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NoIntegers()
{
    Mock<IBar> mockBar = new Mock<IBar>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    mockBar.SetupGet(x => x.Integers)
           .Returns(new List<int>());

    Assert.IsFalse(new Foo(mockBar.Object).AreThereIntegers());
}

[TestMethod]
public void HasIntegers()
{
    Mock<IBar> mockBar = new Mock<IBar>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    mockBar.SetupGet(x => x.Integers)
           .Returns(new List<int>{ 3, 5, 6});

    Assert.IsTrue(new Foo(mockBar.Object).AreThereIntegers());
}
```

Comment: The problem with returning a concrete class is that I can't assert that nothing was changes on it.  It is allot neater though.

Comment: @BanksySan You don't need to test and mock everything. .NET BCL is a stable dependency, you have to assume it just works and test your own code.

Comment: I know not to test the framework, I meant the application code.  The actual code is larger that the sample code I put up, I want to assert that nothing changes to the objects in the enumerable.

Comment: @BanksySan You can return a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) instance from the mock. It will thrown an exception if collection is modified and your test will fail.

Comment: IEnumerable is also read-only, but that doesn't mean that the objects within it are immutable, they could still have properties changed...  I have, however, come around to your solution.  it ticks all the boxes and it allot easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed!

Not pretty, but this is the mocking that's needed:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void NoIntegers()
    {
        Mock<IBar> mockBar = new Mock<IBar>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        Mock<IEnumerable<int>> mockIntegers = new Mock<IEnumerable<int>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        Mock<IEnumerator<int>> mockEnumerator = new Mock<IEnumerator<int>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockBar
            .SetupGet(x => x.Integers)
            .Returns(mockIntegers.Object);

        mockIntegers
            .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(mockEnumerator.Object);

        mockEnumerator.Setup(x => x.MoveNext()).Returns(false);

        mockEnumerator.Setup(x => x.Dispose());

        Assert.IsFalse(new Foo(mockBar.Object).AreThereIntegers());
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
        IEnumerable<int> Integers { get; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private IBar _bar;

        public Foo(IBar bar)
        {
            _bar = bar;
        }

        public bool AreThereIntegers()
        {
            return _bar.Integers.Any();
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for following up even after accepting another answer. This solution was helpful for me where the accepted answer was not.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the `Any()` method is not directly exposed by the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, but it is defined as [an extension method on `Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I don't think you can set up a call to `Any()` on any mock, because it is essentially a static method.

In this case I think it's preferable to use an instance of `IEnumerable<int>` (ex: an int array) that can be set up to be empty/non-empty, depending on what you are testing.

Comment: Aye, the static-ness was the problem.  Got mislead by the error message.